# Why does AC Conductivty in Drude Theory have an Imaginary and a Real Part?

Tags: solid-state-physics, plasma-physics, conductors

In the Drude Model the direct current (DC) conductivity is given by the following formula:

$$\sigma_0=\frac{ne^2 \tau}{m}$$ where $\tau$ is the relaxation time.

Furthermore, the AC conductivity in the Drude Model is given by this formula:

$$\sigma(\omega)=\frac{\sigma_0}{1-i\omega \tau}$$

one can see that for zero frequency the AC conductivity yields the DC conductivity.

---

In [this](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v438/n7071/pdf/nature04232.pdf) paper by Scheffler et al., the frequency-dependent microwave conductivity of the heavy fermion metal $UPd_2Al_3$ is examied. The following graph is taken from their paper:

[image]

> Why are there two different conductivities? The authors seem to have
>   separated the solution into an imaginary and a real part but I don't
>   understand why the conductivity should have an imaginary part in the
>   first place. Could someone explain to me why there are two curves and not just one?

Comment: I assume you have looked at [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drude_model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drude_model)?

Comment: @honeste_vivere Yes I have. I assume you are referring to this sentence: "The imaginary part indicates that the current lags behind the electrical field, which happens because the electrons need roughly a time $\tau$ to accelerate in response to a change in the electrical field. "

I don't see why this would result in two curves though.

Comment: you should start by understanding the formalism used in this case https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phasor

Comment: @Wolphramjonny Thank you very much for your comment. I looked at the Wikipedia page and it was quite shocking to realize that I didn't really understand waves. I went out and bought Daniel Fleisch's "A Students Guide to Waves" and I will be working through that this week. I am sure, that will solve my problem.

Comment: @qmd - You should look at Whitham's book on "Linear and Nonlinear Waves," which gives probably the most thorough background on waves.  As for the two curves, the real and imaginary parts are separable by definition.

Comment: @honeste_vivere Thank you for the suggestion. I will pick it up from the library tomorrow.