# What is the complex conductivity of a metal?

Tags: electromagnetism, conductors, metals

I was told that it is possible to describe frequency dependent properties of metals in terms of the equations of motions of the charge carriers. In order to do so the Drude model can be exploited and the following relationship can be derived:

$$\sigma _n = \frac{Nq^2}{m(\tau^{-1} - i\omega)}$$

where $\sigma _n$ is the complex conductivity, $N$ is the number of charge carriers per unit volume, $q$ the charge of each carrier, $\tau$ the average scattering time between collisions, and $\omega$ is the frequency of the electric field.

Where does this result come from and how can it be derived? Also, what is its significance?

Comment: Related: [Why does AC Conductivty in Drude Theory have an Imaginary and a Real Part?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/264648/why-does-ac-conductivty-in-drude-theory-have-an-imaginary-and-a-real-part).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This complex conductivity is a simple result of the classical Drude model for the metal conduction. In the Drude model it is assumed that in the metal there is a concentration $n$ of electrons and that an electron has a probability $\frac {1}{\tau}$, $\tau$ is called scattering or relaxation time, for scattering with the lattice for losing its momentum. The motion of the electrons can be described by Newton's law $$m\frac {d v}{d t}=-eE-\frac {mv}{\tau} \tag 1$$ where $m$ is the (effective) electron mass, $v$ the mean electron velocity in field direction, and $E$ is the electric field strength. The last term on the RHS of eq. (1) resembles a "friction term" in the equation of motion. Assuming sinusoid variation of the electric field $$v \propto E \propto \exp(-i\omega t) \tag 2$$ Thus from eq.(1) follows $$v=-\frac{eE}{m}\frac {1}{1/\tau-i\omega}\tag 3$$ This gives the current density $$j=-nev=\frac{ne^2E}{m}\frac {1}{1/\tau-i\omega} \tag 4$$ and thus the complex metal conductivity $$\sigma=\frac{ne^2}{m}\frac {1}{1/\tau-i\omega} \tag 5$$

Comment: What is the physical significance of the complex conductivity? More specifically, what do the real part and the imaginary part represent?

Comment: The complex conductivity relates both the magnitude and the phase of the current density to the magnitude and phase of the applied electric field similar to the current and voltage in an ac circuit are related by the complex conductance. This can be most easily seen when you remember that only real parts of the complex values of current and electric field are used and you express the complex conductivity by the complex exponential $\sigma=|\sigma|\exp( -i\phi)$. Then you see from (2) that $|\sigma|$ is the magnitude of the proportionality constant and $\phi$ is the current-field phase shift.

Comment: thanks for the clarification. In $(1)$ where does the second term come from? Can it be derived?

Comment: @daljit97 - The real part of $\sigma$ thus describes the convective current and the imaginary part corresponds to a displacement current.

Comment: @daljit97 - You can find a good exposition of the Drude model in Chapter 1 of Ashcroft/Mermin, including the equation corresponding to eq. (1).